# How can I create a map combination using Tab in command mode?

Tags: vim

I want to create a key combination that would copy the text under the cursor, open the `:find` command, yank the word and then press Tab to autocomplete to the first filename in the list, so (in 99% of cases) I would have just to press enter to open the file.

```
map <Leader>o yw:find <C-R>"<Tab>
```

However, when I press `<Leader>o`, I get `:find FileName^I` in the command line instead. How can I make it react the same way as if I pressed the  key myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `wildcharm` options:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
map <Leader>o yw:find <C-R>"<C-z>
```

See `:help 'wildcharm'`.

Here is a more solid, non-recursive, alternative that doesn't clobber the unnamed register for no reason:

```
nnoremap <leader>o :find <C-r><C-w><C-z>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But one question: why did you use `nnoremap` instead of `map` in the last solution? For me it works exactly like I want just with `map`

Comment: `:map` is too lazy, covers too many modes and can be affected by recursiveness while `:nnoremap` is restricted to normal mode and immune to recursiveness. The more explicit you are, the better, and you should always use non-recursive mappings *unless* you actually need recursiveness.

Answer (score 1):

The `gf` (*goto file*) command should do the same thing as your mapping. This opens the file whose name is under or after the cursor.

If not getting the expected behaviour, it's worth checking the contents of the `isfname` option (use `set isfname?` to check). This specifies a list of characters that are treated as valid characters for file path names.

It’s also worth checking / setting the contents of Vim’s `path` option which lists the directories which are searched when using `gf`, `:find` and similar commands, e.g., the default setting on MS Windows is `.,,`:

- `.` searches relative to the directory of the file currently being edited
- `,,` (empty string) searches the current directory; use the `cd` command to check (or set) your current directory.

See

- `help gf`
- `help isfname`
- `help path`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to use `gf`, it just uses the provided parameter and doesn't try to autocomplete it. So, what I put cursor at the beginning of `FileName`, I can't go to the file `FileName.cs` with this command.

Comment: @MaxYankov Does the output of `set isfilename?` include a `.` ? BTW, I was tempted to delete this answer since romainl's answer is so good but I think it's better to use default commands where possible.

Comment: Your answer is actually pretty informative, I didn't know about `gf` command at all. I like @romainl way better, but your answer provides valuable information to someone who googles this question, so please don't delete it.

Comment: `E518: Unknown option: isfilename?`

Comment: @MaxYankov Doh! I meant `isfname`.

Comment: Yes, it includes a `.`